# In Gradle how do I reference an imported ant task with special chars?

Tags: ant, groovy, gradle

I have an ant build which contains tasks of format

```
build
build.foo.bar
```

So to add dependencies in gradle the first one is easy

```
build.dependsOn(...)
```

But the second one is interpreted as method nesting. I suspect there's a standard groovy way to do this but I haven't cracked it.

**How do I reference an ant task containing periods in an build.gradle file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
project.tasks['build.foo.bar'].dependsOn(...)
```

should do the trick.

See [Project.tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3atasks), which returns a TaskContainer (extending TaskCollection), and [TaskCollection.getAt()](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskCollection.html#getAt%28java.lang.String%29) which, as its doc says, can be called using the `[]` operator.